# What happened to the other characters in the 1985 "Biff-timeline"?

Tags: back-to-the-future, timeline, back-to-the-future-ii

In *Back to the Future 2*, Jennifer is left on a swing at her house and reality changes around her. **But what happens to all the other main characters, especially the McFly family?**

I know Lorraine is in a high-rise apartment (with cosmetic surgery performed) but I'm keen to learn what happened to the rest of the family and main characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**George McFly = Dead**

> **Lorraine:** *Marty! George, your father is in the same place he's been for the past 12 years.* [takes a sip] *Oak Park Cemetery.*

Biff explicitly states that he killed him, presumably in order to get to Lorraine.

---

**The rest of the family = Not doing so good**

> **Biff:** *Oh, wouldn't I? First your daughter Linda, I'll cancel all her credit cards. She can settle her debts with the bank all by herself. (He walks up the stairs.) Your idiot son, Dave, I'll get his parole revoked. And as for Marty, well, maybe you'd like all three of your kids behind bars just like your brother Joey. One big happy jailbird family.*

---

**Marty = In boarding school**

> **Biff:** *Did you get kicked out of another boarding school?* (Lorraine takes another sip of her drink.) *Damn it Lorraine, do you know how much perfectly good dough I've spent on this no good kid of yours,*

<sub><sup>All quotes from the [BTTF2 script](http://www.angelfire.com/tv2/seaQuestDSV2032/BTTF2.html)</sup></sub>

---

**Jennifer = Unknown**

Her family still live in the same house, albeit with bars on the windows.

> They drove the rest of the way to Jennifer's house.
>
> Even in the dark, Marty could see THE PARKERS in big block Ietters on
> the mailbox.
>
> Marty and Doc managed to get Jennifer out of the car, and gently
> carried her toward the house. Doc nodded ahead to the front porch. - <sub><sup>[BTTF Part 2, A Novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0425118754)</sup></sub>

Presumably she's alive in this timestream or else she would have started to fade but that's about all we know.

---

**Doc Brown = In an insane asylum**

> The paper was dated July 1983. The headline at the top of the page read:
>
> EMMETT BROWN COMMITTED. Crackpot Inventor Declared Legally Insane!

---

**Einstein = Unknown**

Again, since he didn't fade we can assume that he's still alive in this future

Comment: That is when they went back, but Marty and Doc left Jennifer on a swing and reality changed around her, but what happened to the rest of the family when it changed back from Biff running Hill Valley.

Comment: The implication is that they all reverted to the "good" versions from BTTF1

Comment: Did they wake up in the same relative location as they were in the "bad" 1985, as Jennifer did?

Comment: @Steven - Probably not. Or else Marty's mom would have materialised in mid-air and died.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for the info.  I would up vote this answer, but I can't yet.......

Comment: @Steven - No worries. This question will attract a few upvotes for you, I'm sure.